# Home built in 2000 - Is this wall load bearing?

Tags: load-bearing

[image]Would love some help determining if this wall is load bearing. Pics and blueprints attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't read details of your blueprint, but distances are great enough that internal supports are needed.  Suspect that load is carried downward via floor-to-ceiling columns

Comment: Suzy, can you post a picture of the roof framing directly over the wall between the kitchen and dining?

Comment: Yes I'll grab a picture. Thanks all.

Comment: Voting to close. Details never arrived and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

The two partial height walls (to the right with an archway in the top photo, and to the right with two pictures in the bottom photo) are *definitely* not load bearing.  However the columns at the end of them might well be.  (They *may* just be there to stop the partial walls flopping around.)  It is much harder to tell with the full height wall to the kitchen.  We need to see the roof timbers to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not a bearing wall if the only thing above it is manufactured roof trusses.

If it's a hand framed roof, then it might be.

Comment: What about two span trusses?

Comment: @LeeSam I doubt it. There would be a dropped beam in the foyer if these trusses were three point bearing. There isn't a reason for it to be, but sure anything is possible. We almost never use random interior walls for bearing for roof trusses. Exterior walls and the garage common wall are basically it, and girder trusses if we need to change the truss direction.

Comment: At 47’ plus overhangs, I doubt it’s a simple span...especially with a bonus room above. I’d be extra careful and I’d check for footings under those walls.

Comment: @LeeSam the bonus room is supported by room in attic trusses over the garage, not over the living space, so that doesn't come into play here. The length of the truss actually isn't a big deal, they'll just add piggy back trusses on the top to keep the height under 12' to be able to ship it over the road without pilot vehicles. 60' long trusses with only 2 bearing points work, so why wouldn't this? The bigger the triangle, the stronger it is. Haha You don't basically don't have to worry about spans with roof trusses.

Comment: Also, it'd be easier to go up in the attic and take pictures of the trusses over this wall to verify if it's bearing. Go up before or after the sun is up, attics are hot. That's the easiest way to confirm if the walls are needed or not.

Comment: So when you “go up in the attic to verify if it’s bearing “, what are you looking for...? Are you looking to see if the truss “touches” the wall? Or are you looking to see how the truss is fastened to the wall? It will be rather difficult to get to the area by the top of the wall and then scrape all the insulation away from the top of the wall...then carefully replace the insulation. I’ll bet every interior wall in the house touches the bottom of the trusses. They’re not suppose to, if their non-bearing walls, but everyone does it. The only sure method of checking is to verify footings.

Comment: @LeeSam No, don't move any insulation. You're looking to see if the webs connected to the bottom chord with gusset plates are located directly over the wall in question. If there is a gusset plate with webs going into it, then there's a chance it's a bearing wall. If they don't line up with that wall, then it's definitely not a bearing wall. You don't even need to see the gusset plate, just enough of the web to figure out if it's located 12'6" from the exterior wall. You think it's easier to tear up hardwood flooring to verify? Next easiest is to look for a header in that wall above opening